# Find encryption algorithm from a file

Tags: encryption, aes

If I have a file claimed to be "encrypted using AES algorighm", can I verify that their claim is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if you have the key.  (and IV)

Encryption produces arbitrary byte sequences; most algorithms do not have any characteristics about their output.

In fact, [one can design a ciphertext which corresponds to two different plaintexts using two different keys or algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption).

However, depending on what the file is, it may have a (plaintext) header specifying the encryption algorithm (and that header may be lying).

Answer (score 1):

Good encryption schemes are actually designed to hide away all the details of encryption from the encrypted data so if they used a proper application to do the encryption, you should not be able to verify the algorithm used.